# Always On: replication over cross server SQL instances

Tags: sql-server, availability-groups

I do agree, the question is not very clear. Let's explain that.

**Context**: we are wondering if it's a good idea (regarding our business and technical architecture) to use AlwaysOn features (SQLServer 2014).

A consultant told us to have (case of two servers to replicate): two servers (let's call them `S1` and `S2`) in which we have two SQLServer instances (`S1\DB1` plus `S1\DB2` and `S2\DB1` plus `S2\DB2`). 
`S1\DB1` and `S2\DB2` are masters and `S1\DB2` and `S2\DB1` are replicas.

With a schema:

[image]

Instead of basic architecture (4 servers, one SQL instance per server):
[image]

Consultant's point of view: less servers so simpler management and less costs.

**Question**:is that a good way to implement SQLServer AlwaysOn?

Comment: Not enough information.  Are you doing this for HA/DR purpose?  Are these in two data centers? What is your RPO and RTO? Can one host + attached storage take full load of all the application combined on both instances? I am sure there are more questions, that needs to be answered.  I suggest you do not take advise based on the information you provided and make a decision.

Comment: @SqlWorldWide: indeed, there is not much info. Because the question is just about theory. We are in the very beginning of our study and didn't make any definitive conclusion (and maybe we'll forget about AlwaysOn). Of course, in our real use case we will also consider datacenters, servers, performance, and of course we will do real tests. The advice of the consultant was a bit surprising to me, that why I wanted to have another...

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your requirement, both solution are OK.

In first schema, imagine to have a fault on a server. Or you simply need to do updates. Can a single server handle your work load? If yes, you can save money.

You will need to handle correctly multiple IP for server, or different port for the istances, but it is not a problem if your department is skilled.

I mixed mutiple istances in multiple servers, also mixed failover cluster istances with Always ON. My only suggestion is to implement on SQL 2016 or 2017 if you can. It introduces DAG and is a bit more mature.